# Why does byte array return null when saved as an image?

Tags: java

I wrote code to hide message into image, at first I convert the image into byte array and hide the message into image but when I want to convert new byte array into image I get `null`? I know there are many question about this topic , I try the answers but not work.
please can anyone help me?

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReadParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
//import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


        if(args.length==0)
        {
            String dirName="C:\\";
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
            BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("inacup_donut.jpg"));
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
            baos.flush();

            String base64String=Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
            baos.close();

            byte[] bytearray = Base64.decode(base64String);
            int [] int_array=new int [bytearray.length];

            for(int i=0;i<bytearray.length;i++)
            {
            int_array [i]=(int)bytearray[i];
            }//end for loop



            int x []= encodeMessage(int_array,img.getHeight(),img.getWidth(),
                    "message") ;
            System.out.println("read " + x[0]+ " bytes,");

            byte [] new_bytearray = new byte [x.length] ;
            for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
                new_bytearray[i]=(byte)x[i];

            }//end for loop




            BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(new_bytearray));

            ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File(dirName,"snap.jpg")); 

        }


        }//end main function





}//end  class
```

Comment: Which part gives you the `null`?

Comment: What `encodeMessage` is supposed to be?

Comment: @Cirou encodeMessage is function take message and hide it into int_array using LSB algorithm and return int array

Comment: Something happens at that point, because if you comment out the `new_bytearray` creation's part and use the old `bytearray` the `ImageIO.read` works well.

Comment: yes this correct ,i think there is problem in format used ?

Comment: I think that your `new_bytearray` is an invalid byte array for the read method and it returns null. Check your code, i can't reproduce the issue atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following coding:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class EncodeImage  {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{


        if(args.length!=0)
        {
        BufferedImage sourceImage = null;
        try {
            sourceImage = ImageIO.read(new File("inacup_donut.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        int type = sourceImage.getType();
        int w = sourceImage.getWidth();
        int h = sourceImage.getHeight();
        byte[] pixels = null;
        if (type == BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)
        {
            System.out.println("type.3byte.bgr");
            pixels = (byte[]) sourceImage.getData().getDataElements(0, 0, w, h, null);
            //for(int i=0;i<pixels.length;i++)
                //pixels[i]=(byte) (pixels[i]|2);
            System.out.println(pixels[1]);

            int [] int_array=new int [pixels.length];
            for(int i=0;i< pixels.length;i++)
            {
            int_array [i]= pixels[i];
            }//end for loop



            int x []= encodeMessage(int_array,h,w,
                    "message") ;
            System.out.println("read " + x[0]+ " bytes,");
            byte [] new_bytearray = new byte [x.length] ;
            for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            {
                new_bytearray[i]=(byte)x[i];
            }

            try {
                BufferedImage edgesImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                edgesImage.getWritableTile(0, 0).setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, new_bytearray);
                ImageIO.write(edgesImage, "png", new File("snap.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }






        }
        } 
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the encodingMessage method as well.

Comment: @DougHauf  The encodingMessage method is LSB algorithm used to hidden data into image (steganography), I can't post this method because I use it into security project  , there are many resources about this algorithm , google it .